# ¿Cómo tipear correctamente una propiedad retornada desde una función?

Tags: typescript

¿Cómo podría tipear una propiedad de un objeto la cual es retornada en una función?

```
interface IBase {
  d1: {
    c1: string;
  };
  d2: {
    cA: number;
  };
};
const base: IBase = {
  d1: {
    c1: "texto1",
  },
  d2: {
    cA: 999
  }
}
function getPropByKey(key: keyof IBase) {
  //...hace algo
  const r = base[key];
  return r;
}
const bd1 = getPropByKey("d1");
const txt = bd1.c1; // Error de tipado
```

Intenté lograr lo siguiente:

```
const txt = base["d1"].c1;//Tipado correcto
```

Pero proporcionado desde una función que recibe la `key` de la propiedad que se desea retornar.

¿Es posible?, gracias.

Comment: Si no me equivoco, necesitarías de una variable genérica que extienda a las llaves de `IBase`... la sintaxis si no recuerdo mucho.. pero es algo por ahí...

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Amigo como te apruebo la edición a mi pregunta?

Comment: pues como ves es muy común que me coma las tildes, entonces gracias por la edición en lo ortográfico, lo de los espacio en el código si los quitas se pierde los colores de ayuda del código, te lo pregunto porque ya me han hecho correcciones de ortografía y pensé que había una manera de  aprobar ese tipo de ediciones sin necesidad de reconstruir toda la pregunta

Comment: en cuanto a lo de los genéricos `getPropByKey<TGenerico>("d1")` quiero evitarlo porque me hace buscar entre la interfaz el tipo al que le corresponde y enviarlo a la función como tipo genérico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El compilador interpreta tu función como

```
function getProperty(key: keyof IBase): IBase[keyof IBase] {
  ...
}
```

De manera que acepta como parámetro ya sea `d1` o `d2`, pero la salida inferida es `{c1:string} | {cA:number}` y en ella no tiene certeza de la existencia de `c1` o `c4`, sólo que es una de esas dos.

La solución es usar genéricos:

```
function getPropByKey<T extends keyof IBase>(key: T): IBase[T] {
}
```

Con lo cual sabe que la salida ya no es el difuso `IBase[keyof IBase]` sino que la infiere del parámetro.

Respecto a tu comentario

> en cuanto a lo de los genéricos getPropByKey("d1") quiero
> evitarlo porque me hace buscar entre la interfaz el tipo al que le
> corresponde y enviarlo a la función como tipo genérico

En este caso no aplica. No necesitas pasar un parámetro de tipo a la función.

Comment: Esa si es la respuesta correcta, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hola :D puedes acceder en la propiedad  de la siguiente forma :
luego de declarar  funcion getPropByKey() has esto :

```
const bd1 = getPropByKey('d1');
const bd2 = getPropByKey('d2');
const txt1 = bd1['c1'];
const txt2 = bd2['cA'];
console.log(txt1, txt2);
```

con esto ya esta ya estaria en ves de estar retornando esto :

```
const txt = base["d1"].c1;//Tipado correcto
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, pero no es la solución que busco, te explico, en el editor de código (yo uso VSCode) ubica el cursor en `['c1']` dentro de los paréntesis y las comillas sencillas, si tecleas  ctrl+spacio  typescript no detecta (no infiere) que `'c1'` haga parte de la propiedad `d1` de `IBase`, es más, si te pones con el puntero sobre `bd1['c1']` específicamente en `bd1` typescript lo está infiriendo como `{c1:string} | {cA:number}` ,  esa unión `|` de definiciones es la que daña todo.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma que el compilador lo permita es validando la propiedad antes de accederla:

```
interface IBase {
    d1: {
        c1: string;
    };
    d2: {
        cA: number;
    };
}
const base: IBase = {
    d1: {
        c1: 'texto1',
    },
    d2: {
        cA: 999,
    },
};
function getPropByKey(key: keyof IBase) : IBase[keyof IBase] {
    //...hace algo
    const r = base[key];
    return r;
}
const bd1 = getPropByKey('d1');
if ('c1' in bd1) {
    console.log( bd1.c1); // funcionando
}
```